# Straight line on 8-axis

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, linear-algebra, visualization

How would a straight line appear in a 8-axis co-ordinate system. Will it continue to look like a straight line or will it appear like zig-zag line. We can see that straight line appears like a dot in one-dimension, straight line in two-dimension graphs.

Comment: Does your space have 8 coordinates in the same space, or is it a two vector of four. Like $V = [\hat{v},\hat{u}]$ where $\hat{v}=(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and similarly for $\hat{u}$? I say this because a line in 3D is represented by pluecker coordinates with 6 values, and I am trying to understand how this relates to your 8D space.

Answer (score 1):

A straight line also looks like a line in three dimensions; what's new in three dimensions is the ability to build intersecting planes, from which you can construct skew lines (nonintersecting, nonparallel) and three-dimensional objects. In four dimensions you can construct hypersolids. (I'm not sure how much attention the hypercube/tessaract gets outside of *A Wrinkle in Time*, but that's where I learned about it first as a kid.) But in four dimensions you can still construct ordinary solids, ordinary planes, ordinary lines, and ordinary points. A one-dimensional line in a (flat, Euclidean) higher-dimensional space would still look like a one-dimensional line if you projected it onto any two- or three-dimensional subspace for viewing.